# Laurent expansion of the given function

Tags: laurent-series

I have the following question :
Find a Laurent expansion of $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{(z^2 + 1)}$, valid for $|z-3| > 2$.

I have learnt finding the Laurent expansion of functions where the denominator is of the form $(z+a)^n$, but this form in the given question seems to be unfamiliar to me. I guess I need to transform it to the $(z+a)^n$ form, but how do I utilise the condition given (that it is valid for $|z-3| > 2$) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That question makes no sense. The poles of $f$ are $\pm i$ and the distance from $3$ to $\pm i$ is $\sqrt{10}>2$. So, there is no single Laurent series that works in the region $\lvert z-3\rvert>2$.

Comment: May I then assume that the condition given in the question has been misprinted?

Comment: It sure looks like.